# JsonMappingException when passing empty body

Tags: java, json, rest-assured

When trying to pass empty body to the POST request it fails with

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: JsonObject (through reference chain: com.google.gson.JsonObject["asFloat"])
```

So I am trying to pass empty body {} in the POST request by creating:

```
Object body = new JsonObject();
```

It gives me desired object like this: {} (I checked in the network action and it's passed the same way). But when it reaches the  `RequestSpecification body(Object var1);` then it fails (on the 'body' part)

```
given()
                .spec(requestSpecification)
                .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
                .when()
                .body(body).log().all()
                .post(URL)
                .then().log().all().extract().response();
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be sending JSON strings instead of JSON objects? Can you try defining boy as an empty JSON string `{}` and check?

Comment: the reason for that is that I use this method for passing deserialized objects as a body parameter. This is an exception usage

Comment: You need to check the code with the body part and how it's deserializing the object.

Comment: @jacob1989 Could you re-write your question? I read it 5 times, and still don't get your problem. Do you mean when you did `JsonObject body = new JsonObject();` --> Exception, but if you did `Object body = new JsonObject();` --> `{}` and no error ?